# Error during running the pipeline in git

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I have configured my gitlab-ci.yml file . And this was authenticating the envs in the past. However very recently when i tried running it again . I am getting the below error.

> ERROR running auth:sfdxurl:store:  ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '-s'

Below is the sample YML file:

```yaml
# Installations scripts to openssl credentials and Salesforce DX
#
stages:
- Build
- Test
- Staging
- Production

deploy-qa:
  stage: Test
  only:
    refs:
    - develop
  when: manual  
  allow_failure: false
  environment:
    name: QA
  script:

   # Setup SFDX environment variables
  - export CLIURL=https://developer.salesforce.com/media/salesforce-cli/sfdx-linux-amd64.tar.xz  
  - export ROOTDIR=force-app/main/default/
  - export TESTLEVEL=RunLocalTests
  
  # Install Salesforce CLI
  - mkdir sfdx
  - wget -qO- $CLIURL | tar xJ -C sfdx --strip-components 1
  - "./sfdx/install"
  - export PATH=./sfdx/$(pwd):$PATH
  - sfdx --version
   - sfdx update
  - echo "Authenticate - QA Environment"
  - sfdx force:auth:sfdxurl:store --sfdxurlfile $PRP_AUTH_VAR -s -a $CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME
  - echo "Deploy SF metadata..."
  - sfdx force:source:deploy -p $ROOTDIR
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious potential culprit - acknowledging that troubleshooting CI failures is rarely possibly purely by looking at the job definitions - is that `$PRP_AUTH_VAR` is empty. This would result in an attempt to run the command

```
sfdx force:auth:sfdxurl:store --sfdxurlfile -s -a $CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME
```

where `-s` is interpreted as the filename argument to `--sfdxurlfile`.

Comment: Thank you for your response David. However i have added the PRP auth variables  in the settings section. Have uploaded a pic in the initial ask.

But still i am getting this error. So not sure what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what to tell you. The _proximate_ cause seems pretty clear to me. It's very difficult to troubleshoot CI jobs without being hands-on, but I would keep exploring to ensure that that env var is properly made available to this job.